# Parsing XML structure without expanding entities in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xmlreader, entities

I'm trying to extract the structure of an XML document in PHP without expanding the entities within. I'm aware that entities are usually expanded *before* the structure is parsed, and that ignoring this means that the XML may not be well-formed, but I'm parsing XML fragments which might not include the normal XML document header, and so will be missing the entity declarations.

Ideally I'd like a callback when an undeclared entity is found so that I can handle it myself. XMLReader and xml_parser both seem to have no way to turn off the errors these produce during parsing.

Is there any easy way to do this, or will I need to fall back on my own parser (which wouldn't be a disaster - I only need to parse a few tags, and then keep all the text inside them).

Here's an example of some DocBook from the first chapter of the official DocBook guide:

```
<chapter id="ch-gssgml">
<?dbhtml filename="ch01.html"?>
<chapterinfo>
<pubdate>$Date$</pubdate>
<releaseinfo>$Revision$</releaseinfo>
</chapterinfo>
<title>Getting Started<?lb?>with &SGML;/&XML;</title>
<para>
    ...
</para>
</chapter>
```

Trying to parse this just dies as soon as it sees the &SGML; entity.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of browsing through XMLReader: Have you tried this:

[XMLReader::setParserProperty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.setparserproperty.php) in combination with [XMLReader::SUBST_ENTITIES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php#xmlreader.constants.subst-entities)?

Haven't tried anything, just looks promising. Should work like

```
XMLReader::setParserProperty ('SUBST_ENTITIES', 0);
```

It seems there is no documentation on what values SUBST_ENTITIES will accept.

Cheers,

Comment: I tried something similar, but couldn't get it to change behaviour. I may have used the wrong syntax, so I'll give your suggestion a try - thanks for the tip!